# Mercurial: How to make HG LOG to show trivial parent?

Tags: mercurial, revision

According to [HG manual](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html):

> By default this command prints
>   revision number and changeset id,
>   tags, non-trivial parents, user, date
>   and time, and a summary for each
>   commit. When the -v/--verbose switch
>   is used, the list of changed files and
>   full commit message are shown.

I have tried `hg log -v` but still it does not show the trivial parents.

Comment: What does "trivial" mean in this case? One parent? Or is it more complicated than that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `--debug` option.

```
$ hg log --template '{parents}\n' --debug
12:49f2f93d2efdd41c9ffb9dccf4d451e2d8bfbc5f -1:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 
7:012b1bb5d99549a5a7c1a280755fa6336c0b472a -1:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 
10:d6dc52582cfaa0e8be17a5b9da61b55692353afc 11:8ee9fa792548fc30669a34cf39fcc7185aabaa19 
8:d589ca45072469148f833f38918861e8de406e64 -1:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 5):

You can see them visually in 'hg log -G' once you've turned on the [Graphlog Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GraphlogExtension).

In this context "trivial" just means "is the current revision number minus one", so in a situation like this:

```
o  changeset:   1440:fe26f69d4b84
|  user:        dan@scofield.bx.psu.edu
|  date:        Fri Jul 18 12:11:58 2008 -0400
|  summary:     Typo in last commit.
|
o  changeset:   1439:74cbef36b62f
|  user:        dan@scofield.bx.psu.edu
|  date:        Fri Jul 18 12:10:23 2008 -0400
|  summary:     Fix bug in JobWrapper.get_input_fnames(), used by pbs runner, when an input dataset was optional and left empty.
|
o  changeset:   1438:1e111ebb2664
|  user:        James Taylor <james@jamestaylor.org>
|  date:        Thu Jul 17 22:14:40 2008 -0400
|  summary:     Workflows (owned and shared) can now be added to the tool menu.
|
o    changeset:   1437:4a4de494fbf6
|\   parent:      1436:37a7f508eb30
| |  parent:      1431:8b83b7250224
| |  user:        James Taylor <james@jamestaylor.org>
| |  date:        Thu Jul 17 20:42:00 2008 -0400
| |  summary:     Merge.
| |
| o  changeset:   1436:37a7f508eb30
| |  user:        James Taylor <james@jamestaylor.org>
| |  date:        Thu Jul 17 20:40:20 2008 -0400
| |  summary:     Allow loading a specific controller/action in the root middle frame, and use
| |
| o  changeset:   1435:96e1cda02414
| |  user:        James Taylor <james@jamestaylor.org>
| |  date:        Thu Jul 17 20:16:13 2008 -0400
| |  summary:     Fix for scroll panel when dropping while still overlapping the edge.
| |
```

A parent list is only shown for 1437 because for the rest have a single parent that is revision number minus one.

Comment: I know how to show the graph and I know what is the trivial parent, but I would like to know if there is a way to force `hg log` to show the trivial parents:) (I am building graph from `hg log` output and I am now computing parents, but I will throw my code away if `hg log` can do this.)

Comment: There's no way to have hg-log do it, but there are plenty of extensions that export the revision graph in a way that's much easier to parse/consume than log's output.  Check out the Graphviz extension for an example which includes easily tweakable code.

Comment: Ok, thx. It seems more convenient in my situation to keep my trivial parents computing code, since `hg log --template "..."` is enough in my case. Btw. do you know why `hg log -r :` and `hg log` produces output in reversed order -- is it a bug or feature? :)

Comment: The colon syntax does x:y, where x defaults to 0 and y defaults to tip.  Without a -r `hg log` does `-r tip:0` so that folks can do `hg log -l 3` and see the last 3 commits w/ the least possible typing.

Answer (score 4):

The template keyword parents is empty when the only parent is the next node

`hg log --template "{parents}\n" -l 20`

Answer (score 0):

with this simple patch to mercurial sources you'll get all parents in the log:
file cmdutil.py: (line 990 in hg 3.1.2)

```
 def _meaningful_parentrevs(self, log, rev):
    """Return list of meaningful (or all if debug) parentrevs for rev.

    For merges (two non-nullrev revisions) both parents are meaningful.
    Otherwise the first parent revision is considered meaningful if it
    is not the preceding revision.
    """
    parents = log.parentrevs(rev)
    return parents    #<=================add this line
    if not self.ui.debugflag and parents[1] == nullrev:
        if parents[0] >= rev - 1:
            parents = []
        else:
            parents = [parents[0]]
    return parents
```

In mercurial 4.0 find in the file scmutil.py:

```
def meaningfulparents(repo, ctx):
    """Return list of meaningful (or all if debug) parentrevs for rev.

    For merges (two non-nullrev revisions) both parents are meaningful.
    Otherwise the first parent revision is considered meaningful if it
    is not the preceding revision.
    """
    parents = ctx.parents()
    return parents       #<===========================add this line
    if len(parents) > 1:
        return parents
    if repo.ui.debugflag:
        return [parents[0], repo['null']]
    if parents[0].rev() >= intrev(ctx.rev()) - 1:
        return []
    return parents
```

you'll get something like:

```
$ hg log
changeset:   62355:2722bdc1f0fc
branch:      ALL-3158-fortran-memkind
tag:         tip
parent:      62354:82da46786838
parent:      -1:000000000000
user:        Marcos Mayorga <mm@mm-studios.com>
date:        Mon Jan 30 09:12:13 2017 +0000
summary:     memkind smoke tests for FORTRAN

changeset:   62354:82da46786838
branch:      ALL-3158-fortran-memkind
parent:      62194:c98a4c8295ab
parent:      -1:000000000000
user:        Marcos Mayorga <mm@mm-studios.com>
date:        Fri Jan 27 14:38:53 2017 +0000
summary:     create branch

...
```